# How can I give permissions to specific folders on heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, permissions, chmod

I'm trying to install thelia on heroku, but I've problems with permissions on folders. How can I make chmod in the right way?

Here is our buildpack: https://github.com/fzaffo/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/compile

we're getting this result: chmod:

> cannot access ‘/app/cache’: No such file or directory
>   (seems it can't find folders in /app)

Here's the test: http://eglaan.herokuapp.com

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include `composer.json` and shoot the `chmod` command from there:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "compile": [
      "chmod -R 777 var/",
      "chmod 755 etc/",
      "chmod 644 etc/config.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I set "chmod 600 folder/file.jpg" but i can still access the file from public url. Anything am doing wrong?