# "chown -R $user:www-data storage" this command is not working in heroku bash. can anyone know how to do this

Tags: php, laravel

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9osa.png)

php version => PHP 7.4.23  (cli)
laravel version => Laravel Framework 7.30.4

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455888/how-can-i-give-permissions-to-specific-folders-on-heroku help?

Comment: no its not working.

Comment: Please do not share images of stuff that could be shared in text form. Also, what have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`$USER` is a special shell variable (also referred to as an enviroment variable) that will always contain the username of the user running the process.

`$user` is a different (and empty) variable.

Comment: i know about this. this is not a issue

Comment: You're running as a user that isn't allowed to change the file permissions. Use sudo or another user that does have access to the files.

Comment: sudo command is not working in heroku and 
i try all user list but this app show the same error on every user.

Comment: Well, what is the folder owned by? Run ``ls -la`` and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

User variable is written in capital letters

```sh
chown -R $USER:www-data storage
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it